# Migrations are not being processed

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm trying to migrate election file but no migrations are being proceesed.

I've tried running truffle migrate --reset and remigrating process but nothing happens.

Elections.sol

pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

```
contracts Election{
    string public candidate;

    constructor() public{
        candidate="Candidate 1"
    }
}
```

2_deploy_contracts.js

```
var Election = artifacts.require("./Election.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Election);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you have compiled your smart contract?

So, at first fix syntax errors:

```
contract Election {
    string public candidate;

    constructor() public{
        candidate="Candidate 1";
    }
}
```

Then compile your contract:

```
truffle compile
```

After that, migrate:

```
truffle migrate
```